# pythonの比較演算子

Tags: python, python3

python初心者です。pythonではインポートされたファイルの中身は実行される。
main() => print("Hello") と処理が実行される。と書いてあります。意味が理解できません
教えて下さい。 例えばa >= b はaはｂ以上ですが>=のいみも理解できません。

Answer (score 2):

この `=>` は少なくとも比較演算子ではありません。おそらく地の文の矢印です。

Comment: そうですね。比較演算子ではないですね。
僕は初心者だから「比較演算子」と思って調べていたのですが、スッキリ致しました。有難うございました。

Comment: 文脈が文脈なのでさすがにそうはならなさそうなものの言語によってはラムダ式にしか見えない書きたですね……w